# How to remove this warning about conluent.monitoring.interceptor?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm publishing a message to Kafka using `KafkaTemplate` in Spring Boot 2.2.2 service using `Spring-Kafka`. The messages are being published successfully however my logs are flooded with the following warning as soon as I publish the first message:

```
[Producer clientId=confluent.monitoring.interceptor.fagfgfsgas-1] Bootstrap broker confluent-kafka.eabcd.com:1234 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

I think I either misspelled one of the properties or misplaced it but I can't figure out what. This is what my yaml looks like:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      client-id: "abcd"
      acks: 1
      bootstrap-servers: confluent-kafka.eabcd.com:1234
      key-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
      confluent.monitoring.interceptor.sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
      confluent.monitoring.interceptor.security.protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      confluent.monitoring.interceptor.sasl.jaas.config: 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="username" password="password";'
      properties:
        request.timeout.ms: 10000
        retry.backoff.ms: 500
        schema.registry.url: https://confluent-schemaregistry.abcdef.com
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: http
        sasl.jaas.config: 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="username" password="password";'
        security.protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
        sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
        interceptor.classes: io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is saying that your connection to `bootstrap-servers` is unable to be established

I suggest you debug the code without `interceptor.classes`

And `confluent.monitoring.interceptor` things need to go under properties section

Comment: Okay, moving those under properties seems to have resolved the issue however now I get these in the logs:

```The configuration 'confluent.monitoring.interceptor.sasl.mechanism' was supplied but isn't a known config.
The configuration 'confluent.monitoring.interceptor.security.protocol' was supplied but isn't a known config.
The configuration 'confluent.monitoring.interceptor.sasl.jaas.config' was supplied but isn't a known config.```

Comment: That's a warning. Ignore it